# Cannot connect to github

Tags: git, github

I'm in China and cannot pull, clone or push to github. I'm using a vpn but it still doesn't work. I'm working home from my computer, so it can't be my firewall. I also tried to turn it of briefly, but it didn't change anything.

fatal: unable to access '': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out.

I've tried setting and unsetting proxies, without success. I've googled for at least a couple of hours, but without prevail.

Any help would be very appreciated and valuable to me.

Comment: And through SSH?

Comment: Run DNS through VPN too. Use public DNS like OpenDNS, Google DNS, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and rapport back

Comment: I know this question has been left for a **bit**, but have you checked to see if **port 443** is available, or **exists**?

Comment: That was the answer. For some reason my port 443 is closed. Will have to open it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If your git was already set to something and you only copied that folder to some other location, simply run:

```
git config --global http.proxy ""
```

And you can pull again :)

Comment: Google "is github accessible in china" - Interesting results come up.

Comment: I did as you said. Now I get this message instead "fatal: unable to access '': Could not resolve host: github.com." But I think it might be the great firewall that hinders it...

Comment: You are saying "Google and Github are not accessible from china"?

Comment: It has been working fine until recently though. I've been living and working here the past few years. Perhaps the blockade just became stronger. Perhaps I should migrate everything to bitbucket or gitlab

Answer (score 1):

One Google Search came up with interesting results..(`Is github accessible in china`)

> On January 21, 2013, GitHub was blocked in China using DNS hijacking. Confirming the block, a spokesperson for GitHub said: "It does appear that we're at least being partly blocked by the Great Firewall of China".

I hope this clears things up for you :)

Comment: I read that too. But I also read this:

_The block was lifted on January 23, 2013 after an online protest on Sina Weibo.[8]_

Comment: Is it possible that China put the firewall back up? (I don't know what else could be causing this.)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed very possible